# Trying to capitalise result of \gls

Tags: macros, glossaries

I'm trying to capitalise the whole of an acronym. I have the acronym:

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{wt}{WT}{wild type}
```

using `\gls{wt}` generates wild type (WT) as expected.

However attempting to use `\MakeUppercase{\gls{wt}}` fails with no glossary entry for WT. So its just capitalising what goes into the `\gls` command.

I've tried `MakeUppercase{\expandafter{\gls{wt}}` But this doesn't work it just throws Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }

I've also tried `\edef\mycommand{\gls{wt}}\MakeUppercase{\mycommand}` but the result is the same.

So question is how to I get \gls{wt} to fully expand before being passed to \MakeUppercase

Comment: Just so I understand, you want only a single instance made uppercase?  Furthermore, you want "WILD TYPE" and not "Wild Type", is that correct?

Comment: yeah thats right

Comment: Also I know \GLS{wt} would work but I'd like to pass it with a bunch of other text to \MakeUppercase along with \gls{wt}

Answer (score 1):

> So question is how to I get `\gls{wt}` to fully expand before being
> passed to \MakeUppercase

You can't. Because `\gls` is not a fully expandable command.

In order to prevent the erroneous uppercasing of the argument `wt` you probably can load the package [textcase](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) with the `overload`-option:

The package brings along commands `\MakeTextUppercase` and `\MakeTextLowercase` which do the same as `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowerCase`.
But there is a feature: The argument of the macro `\NoCaseChange` will not be changed.
The `overload`-option makes `\MakeUppercase` equal to `\MakeTextUppercase` and `\Makelowercase` equal to `\MakeTextLowercase`.

Using `\NoCaseChange` you can prevent the erroneous uppercasing of the argument `wt`.

This does only solve a part of the problem. The problem of getting the result of `\gls` uppercased is still not solved. You need to decide "by hand" whether to use `\gls` or `\GLS` or `\Gls`.

You can, e.g., do:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{wt}{WT}{wild type}

\begin{document}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} uppercase}|:\\
First use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} uppercase}\\
Second use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} uppercase}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} LOWERCASE}|:\\
First use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} LOWERCASE}\\
Second use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\GLS{wt}} LOWERCASE}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} uppercase}|:\\
First use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} uppercase}\\
Second use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} uppercase}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}|:\\
First use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}\\
Second use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\Gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} uppercase}|:\\
First use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} uppercase}\\
Second use: \MakeUppercase{uppercase. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} uppercase}

\glsreset{wt}
\verb|\MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}|:\\
First use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}\\
Second use: \MakeLowercase{LOWERCASE. \NoCaseChange{\gls{wt}} LOWERCASE}

\end{document}
```

[image]